# How to Add Custome Validation Message on Form Field in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

I want to add Range validation for date field which should work as form validation in Angular.
I am getting all validations for each field from API as below,

```
{
  "name":"PolicyDateEnd",
  "display":"Expiration Date",
  "description":"Enter Expiration Date of Coverage",
  "validators":[
  {
  "type":"required",
  "message":"Expiration Date is Required"
  }
  ],
  "dataType":"dateTime",
  "nullable":true
  }
```

Here, Required validation is working fine, but now I need to validate year of date which should not be less than 1900 and should not be grater than 9999.

My expectation is, it should work similar to Required validation like Form validations.
I have created subscriber to check date and I am able to validate year, but not able to display message as it is populating for required validation.

[image]

So, how to add validation message on page, below control, when user entered date which have not valid year?

Comment: How are you binding this required validator to your form control?

Comment: by using formControlName attribute.

Comment: Could you also upload your form html and form group initialization in component?